# Datastax in Azure VM

Tags: azure, cassandra, datastax

I have Datastax dse running in a Centos VM which is hosted in Microsoft Azure.

Heres the thing: I am unable to ping my host, but can connect to it through ssh(from Ubuntu) or putty(from Windows) just fine. And once I start up dse, I am trying to use Datastax DevCenter to access it.

I have set:

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
```

in cassandra.yaml

And the `listen_address` and the `rpc_address` have been set to localhost.

And when I try to connect using DevCenter using the port 9042, I am getting an error indicating that All host(s) tried for query failed. com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException. Cannot connect.

I check the port 9042 and heres the netstat -anp result

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

Can anyone tell me if theres something wrong with my implementation? Im a newbie to Cassandra and datastax btw.

*Solution*

It was just a firewall issue. Connection can be made when accessing from another network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listen address = blank and rpc address = 0.0.0.0. If that doesn't work, try specifying the external ip for both.

Comment: Is there any way to find the external facing IP for an Azure VM?

Comment: What ip are you using from devcentre? What ip do external clients use to connect to it? That'll be the one.

Comment: External clients can connect to the Azure VM using either an external Virtual IP or the host name. And Im able to telnet to the system using both host name and ip address, but DevCenter does not connect.